Why can't my code print in the console, even thought it doesn't show an error?
why is my code not showing in the console? It doesn't even show error. It shows nothing in the console and I am not seeing any syntax or compilation error.
public class Practice11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int weight = 116; 
        if (weight < 116) {
            System.out.println(" Eat 5 banana splits! ");
        }
        else if (weight > 116 && weight < 130) {
            System.out.println(" Eat a banana split! ");
        }
        else if (weight > 131 && weight < 200) {
            System.out.println(" Perfect! ");
        }
        else if (weight > 200) {
            System.out.println("Plenty of banana splits have been consumed!");
        }
    }
}

I was trying to write a code with multiple if else statements. I was expecting results in the console with the condition provided below, this is the practice:
Write a series of if statement statements that evaluates a person’s weight on the following criteria:
• A weight less than 116 pounds, output: Eat 5 banana splits!
• A weight between 116 pounds and 130 pounds, output: Eat a banana split!
• A weight between 131 pounds and 200 pounds, output: Perfect!
• A weight greater than 200 pounds, output: Plenty of banana splits have been consumed!

What do you think should be printed? 116 does not satisfy any of the conditions in the code.

116 is neither less than nor greater than 116.

It is always strange to see the same value in such conditions, and often not just a code smell. Better write it like
if (value <= 115) { 
  // something for values up to 115
} else if (value <= 130) {
  // something for 116 - 130
} else if (value <= 200 {
  // something for 131 - 200
} else {
  // for values greater than 200
}

the else part corresponds to the opposite condition of the previous if - there is no need to test it again.
It is easier to read (IMHO) and harder to make errors like skipping some value. Also less risk of changing one value and forgetting to change the same value in a second condition.

These kind of functionality can be solved by using the NavigableMap functionality
(once you are allowed or learned how to use it)
For example using a TreeMap:
NavigableMap<Integer, String> messages = new TreeMap<>(
    Map.of(
   // lower, message
          0, "Eat 5",    // or Integer.MIN_VALUE, "Eat 5"
        116, "Eat one", 
        131, "Perfect", 
        201, "Plenty")
    );

// ...

String msg = messages.floorEntry(weight).getValue();
// NullPointer if weight is negative
// unless using MIN_VALUE instead of -1 above


Your condition is not declared to print it
int weight = 116; 

if (weight < 116) {
    System.out.println("Eat 5 banana splits!");
} else if (weight >= 116 && weight <= 130) {
    System.out.println("Eat a banana split!");
} else if (weight >= 131 && weight <= 200) {
    System.out.println("Perfect!");
} else if (weight > 200) {
    System.out.println("Plenty of banana splits have been consumed!");
}


You added four characters to ten lines of code.  Such a small difference is quite hard for people to see.  Your answer would be better if you explained exactly what you changed and why.

also there is no need to check weight >= 116 in the else part since the weight can only be >= 116 at that point (otherwise the block after if (weight < 116) would be executed and not the else one)

There are basically two errors occurred inside your code that is the main method should be in a class and second one is you did not declare the condition to execute it.

you initialized  int weight = 116.
if (weight < 116)      -- false --> as weight is not less that 116.
if (weight > 116 && weight < 130)   --  false  --> as weight is not greater than 116, && means both condition should be true.
if (weight > 130 && weight < 200)  -- false --> as weight is not greater than 130,&& means both condition should be true.
if (weight > 200)  -- false -- as weight is not > than 200.
Ultimately all conditions are false hence you are not able to see output on console.
If you want to print something ,try the weight values within the range with respect to condition.

public class Practice11 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int weight = 116; 
    if (weight < 116) {
        System.out.println("Eat 5 banana splits!");
    } else if (weight >= 116 && weight < 130) {
        System.out.println("Eat a banana split!");
    } else if (weight >= 130 && weight <= 200) {
        System.out.println("Perfect!");
    } else if (weight > 200) {
        System.out.println("Plenty of banana splits have been consumed!");
    }
}

}

check this you have not delare print

Please don't post code-only answers. Explain what was wrong and what you changed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
